# BeginInvoke not supported on .NET core? (PlatformNotSupported exception)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cross-platform, .net-core

I've ported a library FluentFTP to .NET standard/.NET core but the async methods use BeginInvoke within an async/await block. So its something like this:

```
async ConnectAsync(){
   BeginConnect();
}
void BeginConnect(){
   BeginInvoke(...)   << error at this point
}
```

At that point I get a PlatformNotSupported exception. What can be done to support this on .NET core?

- Full info [here](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP/issues/142#issuecomment-316120234).
- Full code here: [ConnectAsync](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP/blob/master/FluentFTP/Client/FtpClient_Connection.cs#L1236), [BeginConnect](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP/blob/master/FluentFTP/Client/FtpClient_Connection.cs#L1210).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Asynchronous I/O methods should not use `Delegate.BeginInvoke`. That's exposing a [fake-asynchronous wrapper](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) for a synchronous method that should be asynchronous in the first place. The whole design needs re-evaluation.

[.NET Core does not support `Delegate.BeginInvoke`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5940) for very good reasons. It's possible that .NET Core 2.0 may decide to support them (because Microsoft IMO is making some poor design decisions with v2).

But back to the original problem: the solution is to [do the `//TODO`](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP/blob/master/FluentFTP/Client/FtpClient_Connection.cs#L1237): implement `ConnectAsync` as a true asynchronous method. Then it's pretty straightforward to implement `BeginConnect` and `EndConnect` as wrappers around `ConnectAsync`.

Comment: Do you know if InvokeAsync() is safe? So is it the best to change BeginInvoke() in InvokeAsync() or to change in Task.Run(() => ...Invoke())?

Comment: @C-SharpDeveloper: I'm not sure what `InvokeAsync()` you're referring to.

Comment: A I see now, only Delegate.BeginInvoke() seems to be not supported. I changed also the references of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to Task.Run(); there a method InvokeAsync() would be also possible

Answer (score 34):

The motivation for implementing a "true" async method is clear, as stated by @Steven_Cleary, but sometimes you have legacy code you cannot simply make async. For those in desperate need for keeping the old interface: Use `Task.Run`. E.g. when you had

```
IAsyncResult ar = someDelegate.BeginInvoke(state, null, null);
```

and use properties of `ar` in order to see when the task is finished, you are in luck because the equivalent with Tasks is:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => someDelegate(state));
```

The good news is that the `Task` class implements `IAsyncResult` such that you can recycle your existing code.
Later when you know the delegate has finished, you might have called

```
someDelegate.EndInvoke();
```

which is neither supported by .NET Core. This can the be replaced by

```
task.Wait();
```

It eventually throws exceptions your delegate has thrown, just like `EndInvoke`.
This worked in our migration to .NET Core.

Comment: Notes: (a) If your delegate returns a value, `var returnValue = someDelegate.EndInvoke();` becomes `var returnValue = task.Result;` (rather than `Wait()`). (b) Task.Wait()/Result wraps exceptions in an `AggregateException`, contrary to `EndInvoke`, so it might be necessary to unwrap them.

Comment: To [avoid wrapping exceptions](https://web.archive.org/web/20140222150202/http:/blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx), you can use `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `task.Wait()`/`task.Result`.